# Display SQL values group in date

Tags: php, sql, sorting, group-by

How can I sort in PHP a SQL query grouping by date...

I have this table

```
id  date                  Title
1   2012-12-19 11:00:00   Value 10
2   2013-01-04 09:00:00   Value 15
3   2013-01-04 20:00:00   Value 18
4   2013-01-04 21:00:00   Value 5
5   2013-01-07 09:00:00   Value 8
6   2013-01-07 09:40:00   Value 11
7   2013-01-07 11:00:00   Value 12
```

And I would like to sort by month like so

```
December 19
11:00:00      Value 10

January 04
09:00:00      Value 15
20:00:00      Value 18
21:00:00      Value 5

January 07
09:00:00      Value 8
09:40:00      Value 11
11:00:00      Value 12
```

Comment: SQL isn't suited for presentation layer, it's for getting the data.  Then let PHP do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query and use PHP loop to get your desired result. You just need to split id, time and title values inside your PHP loop to format data for display.

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS id,
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %e') AS Date,
GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%H:%i:%s')) AS TimeValue,
GROUP_CONCAT(title) AS Title
FROM abc
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY MONTH(date) DESC
```

**OUTOUT**

```
ID          DATE            TIMEVALUE                       TITLE
1           December 19     11:00:00                        Value 10
2,3,4       January 4       09:00:00,20:00:00,21:00:00      Value 15,Value 18,Value 5
5,6,7       January 7       09:00:00,09:40:00,11:00:00      Value 8,Value 11,Value 12
```

**SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec3a8/6**

**UPDATE:**

OUTPUT

```
ID          DATE                TIMEVALUE
1           December 19         11:00:00___Value 10
2,3,4       January 4           09:00:00___Value 15,20:00:00___Value 18,21:00:00___Value 5
5,6,7       January 7           09:00:00___Value 8,09:40:00___Value 11,11:00:00___Value 12
```

PHP CODE: I'm assuming you have array like below on the basis of above query output.

```
<?php
$data = array(
        0=>array(
            'id'=>1,
            'date'=>'December 19',
            'time_value'=>'11:00:00___Value 10',
        ),
        1=>array(
            'id'=>2,3,4,
            'date'=>'January 4',
            'time_value'=>'09:00:00___Value 15,20:00:00___Value 18,21:00:00___Value 5',
        ),
        2=>array(
            'id'=>5,6,7,
            'date'=>'January 7',
            'time_value'=>'09:00:00___Value 8,09:40:00___Value 11,11:00:00___Value 12',
        )    
    );
if(is_array($data))
{
    foreach($data as $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            echo '<br />'.$value['date'].'<br />';
            $arrTime = explode(',', $value['time_title']);
            if($arrTime)
            {
                foreach($arrTime as $time)
                {
                    $arrTimeTitle = explode('_', $time);
                    echo $arrTimeTitle[0]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$arrTimeTitle[1]."<br />";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Final PHP output:

```
December 19
11:00:00     Value 10

January 4
09:00:00     Value 15
20:00:00     Value 18
21:00:00     Value 5

January 7
09:00:00     Value 8
09:40:00     Value 11
11:00:00     Value 12
```

Comment: @RicardoCapistran: For PHP, please check the updated part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` function in your sql. You can achieve this in one query rather than you try multiple loops in PHP.

EG:-

```
SELECT 
          id,GROUP_CONCAT(date, value, '+') 
FROM 
          tablename 
GROUP BY 
          date 
ORDER BY 
          date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT
  id,
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %e') as DateValue,
  DATE_FORMAT(date,'%h:%i:%s %p') as TimeValue,
  GROUP_CONCAT(Title)
from mytable
group by DATE(date)
ORDER BY MONTH(date) desc
```

Output

```
id  |   DateValue   |   TimeValue       |   Title
----------------------------------------------------------
1   |   December 19 |   11:00:00        |   Value   10 
2   |   January 4   |   09:00:00        |   Value 15,Value 18,Value 5 
5   |   January 7   |   09:00:00        |   Value 8,Value 11,Value 12
```

On the front end with php explode Title and you will get an array

```
$titles = explode(',',$row['Title']);
```

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(date,'%h:%i:%s') as TimeValue will return time in 12 hour format, and you should use 24 hour format becuase in the problem time is in 24 hour format. so use %H instead of %h

Answer (score 0):

You should try to do this with PHP instead of SQL.

You can retrieve the data through SQL using ORDER BY date then use PHP to capture the format the date using "date()" function and then only print time portion from date field and title field until the date portion matches with previously grabbed date portion.